# Trigger to copy deleted rows to another identical table with Cascade Delete On

Tags: mysql, innodb, trigger, query

I have two tables.
Sale and SaleProducts

SaleProducts contains all the products that have a Sale.

1 sale, many products. (1 to many)

`SaleProducts` has a relation to `Sale` with On Delete set to `CASCADE`.

When I delete a Sale it **deletes** (because of the On Delete cascade) all the `SaleProducts` related to the `Sale`.

Can i define a TRIGGER like `ON DELETE` that will COPY before deleting, all the rows into an identical tables of Sale and SaleProducts for History saving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define trigger `BEFORE DELETE` on main (Sale) table which will copy all records from slave (SaleProducts) table, which may be deleted by cascade operation, to an archive table.

Define `AFTER DELETE` trigger which will copy the record deleted from main table.

If there are records in both archives - the deletion was carried out. All records in both archive tables are valid.

If there are records in SaleProducts archive and there is no appropriate record in Sale archive - the delete operation was not performed due to some error, and those records must be removed from SaleProducts archive table.